# Spivak, Ch. 15, Problem 32: Doubt on step in proof of specific case of Sturm Comparison Theorem.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation

The following problem is from Chapter 15 of Spivak's *Calculus*. It is a question with multiple items, but my question is about two relatively simple steps in part $(c)$.

> *32. Suppose that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ satisfy
>
> $$\phi_1''+g_1\phi_1=0\tag{1}$$
>
> $$\phi_2''+g_2\phi_2=0\tag{2}$$
>
> and that $g_2>g_1$.
>
> (a) Show that
>
> $$\phi_1''\phi_2-\phi_2''\phi_1-(g_2-g_1)\phi_1\phi_2=0\tag{3}$$
>
> (b) Show that if $\phi_1(x)>0$ and $\phi_2(x)>0$ for all $x$ in
> $(a,b)$, then
>
> $$\int_a^b [\phi_1''\phi_2-\phi_2''\phi_1]>0\tag{4}$$
>
> and conclude that
>
> $$[\phi_1'(b)\phi_2(b)-\phi_1'(a)\phi_2(a)]-[\phi_1(b)\phi_2'(b)-\phi_1(a)\phi_2'(a)]>0\tag{5}$$
>
> (c) Show that in this case we cannot have $\phi_1(a)=\phi_1(b)=0$.
> Hint: Consider the sign of $\phi_1'(a)$ and $\phi_1'(b)$.
>
> (d) Show that the equations $\phi_1(a)=\phi_1(b)=0$ are also
> impossible if $\phi_1>0$, $\phi_2<0$ or $\phi_1<0,\phi_2>0$ or
> $\phi_1<0,\phi_2<0$ on $(a,b)$. (You should be able to do this with
> almost no extra work.)
>
> The net result of this problem may be stated as follows: if $a$ and
> $b$ are consecutive zeros of $\phi_1$, and $\phi_2$ must have a zero
> somewhere between $a$ and $b$. This result, in a slightly more general
> form, is known as the Sturm Comparison Theorem. As a particular
> example, any solution of the differential equation
>
> $$y''+(x+1)y=0$$

I have a question about a step in the proof of $(c)$.

Let me go through the proofs of all the items to get to $(c)$.

**(a)**

Simply multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$ by $\phi_2$ and $\phi_1$, respectively.

$$\phi_1''\phi_2+g_1\phi_1\phi_2=0$$

$$\phi_2''\phi_1+g_2\phi_2\phi_1=0$$

Then subtract the second equation from the first to obtain the desired result $(3)$.

**(b)**

For $x\in (a,b)$ we have $\phi_1\phi_2(g_2-g_1)>0$ so $(3)$ is $>0$.

Therefore, from $(3)$ we have

$$\phi_1''\phi_2-\phi_2''\phi_1=(g_2-g_1)\phi_1\phi_2>0$$

Hence

$$\int_a^b [\phi_1''\phi_2-\phi_2''\phi_1]>0$$

But since $[\phi_1'\phi_2-\phi_1\phi_2']'=\phi_1''\phi_2-\phi_2''\phi_1$, the FTC2 tells us that the integral above is

$$[\phi_1'(b)\phi_2(b)-\phi_1(b)\phi_2'(b)]-[\phi_1'(a)\phi_2(a)-\phi_1(a)\phi_2'(a)]$$

which, after rearranging the terms, gives us the desired $(5)$

**(c)**

Assume $\phi_1(a)=\phi_1(b)=0$.

Then, from $(5)$ we obtain

$$\phi_1'(b)\phi_2(b)-\phi_1'(a)\phi_2(a)>0\tag{6}$$

**So it is at this point that I have questions.**

I believe we can say that $\phi_1'(a)\geq 0$ and $\phi_1'(b)\leq 0$, otherwise we'd have negative values of $\phi_1$ on $(a,b)$. **Is this justification correct?**

Next, if we can say that $\phi_2(a)\geq 0$ and $\phi_2(b)\geq 0$ then the expression in $(6)$ is actually negative, ie

$\phi_1'(b)\phi_2(b)-\phi_1'(a)\phi_2(a)\leq 0$

The solution manual justifies this step by saying that "clearly"

> $$\phi_2(a)\geq 0\tag{7}$$
>
> $$\phi_2(b)\geq 0\tag{8}$$

**Why can we conclude $(7)$ and $(8)$?** It seems like this would depend on $\phi_2$ being continuous, but this is not stated in the problem.

Comment: Your first justification is correct, though you should definitely add in the details for your own benefit.  As for your second question, the argument appears to depend on continuity. $\phi_2$ is differentiable so it is continuous (actually, it is twice continuously differentiable). The author hasn't really specified the domains that we're working with, however. I could try writing an answer about this if you want, with further details.

Comment: Ah, that is true. It is differentiable, therefore continuous. Silly mistake not seeing that.